# How to set height to host element and not the @media class(for the same element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a nav-bar which will be displayed only on desktop/laptop versions and not on mobile versions.

```
:host{
height:auto;
display:block;
}

@media(max-width: 768px)
{
:host
{
background:none;
height:auto;
padding: 0 10 10px 0;
}
}
```

The issue here is that, I need to set a min-height for the host element,which should not reflect if the user is in mobile view. I tried setting like the following in the component.ts file(ngAfterViewInit)

```
document.getElementById('left-nav').style.minHeight = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

But this is not working when the user views in mobile. When viewing in mobile version, it should set min-height as "auto" and on other versions "window.innerHeight"

can anyone provide a suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try using this method.

```css
:host(.special-custom-element) {
  //styles here
}
```

Comment: Hi Abraham,
Thanks for the suggestion. But I need to set the window.innerHeight, which can be done only in TS file and not CSS

Comment: I have found a workaround for this!

 if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
set height here for mobile view
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
     Code here for mobile view
}
```